# How do you to save and load a tensorflow model that has a feature_layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following this tutorial with my own dataset: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv. 
This was my squential of the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=[1]),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

Now, I want to save the trained model so that I can use the model in a different program.

The first way I used was using checkpoint callbacks.

```
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1, period=10)


def train():
    model.fit(train_data, epochs=50)#, callbacks=[cp_callback])
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate([[0],[0.4],[0.6],[1],[4.56],[2.1]],  [[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[0]])
    print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

However, this didn't work because in the other program that I wanted to use the model, I wasn't able to copy the exact shape of the model:

```
def create_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=[1]),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

I also tried this:

```
numeric_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('numeric', shape=[1])
numeric_columns = [numeric_column]

preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(numeric_columns)

def create_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    preprocessing_layer,
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

... but it still didn't work.

After that, I tried to use `model.save("myModel.h5")` but this won't save at all, and now I'm lost.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Saver](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/Saver) class member functions: `saver.save` and `saver.restore`.
See this [tutorial](https://cv-tricks.com/tensorflow-tutorial/save-restore-tensorflow-models-quick-complete-tutorial/) for an explicit instruction.

Comment: Probably not since Saver saves a session in Tensorflow. For Keras we do not have to manage session explicitly. Keras provides functions to save and load a model itself, for example see [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/)